# Node.js addon timer context

Tags: c++, node.js, libuv

The libuv timer methods are documented [here](http://nikhilm.github.com/uvbook/utilities.html) and provide a way for a Node.js addon to recieve a callback at regular intervals to perform arbitrary processing.

```
uv_timer_t timer;
uv_timer_init( uv_default_loop(), &timer);
uv_timer_start( &timer, callback, 0, interval );
```

Here *callback* is the timeout method, with prototype:

```
void callback( uv_timer_t *handle, int status );
```

How do I supply a context, preferably in the form of a *void**, to the timer callback procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a context by assigning a pointer to it to data member of the uv_timer_t structure, like so:

```
uv_timer_t timer;
timer.data = context;
```

Comment: I'm worried that this is not documented, but it's *a* solution.